# Why the Login web page isn't showing in webBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, webbrowser-control

I am using C# to login to a local web page. 
I am using webBrowser in order to display the page after the log. 
First, I navigate to page then I fill the username & password then I invoke a click.The element to be clicked is recognized; so I assume that the click happened. But the result page isn't showing, nothing appears when I execute.
I tried this:

```
        public WebBrowser webBrowser;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(LoginEvent);

            webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;

            webBrowser.Navigate("http://192.168.1.100/login.html");
        }


         private void LoginEvent(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            WebBrowser webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;

            //To execute the event just one time
            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= LoginEvent;


            //load page's document
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document;

            doc.GetElementById("u").SetAttribute("value", "admin");

            doc.GetElementById("pw").SetAttribute("value", "123456");

            foreach (HtmlElement elem in doc.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me please to figure why the page isn't showing?

Answer (score 0):

1) Your `WebBrowser` object is a local variable in your `MainWindow()` constructor.

This object is being deposed once the `MainWindow` constructor ends.

You need to declare the `WebBrowser` object as a class member.

2) There might be a multiple `DocumentComplete` events being fired. You need to filter out all iFrame events and wait before the page being fully loaded:

```
private void LoginEvent(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // filter out non main documents
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
        return; 

    //To execute the event just one time
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= LoginEvent;

    //load page's document
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document;

    doc.GetElementById("u").SetAttribute("value", "admin");

    doc.GetElementById("pw").SetAttribute("value", "123456");

    foreach (HtmlElement elem in doc.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering but it didn't work, I tried to declare it as a field but nothing changed.

Comment: it also didn't work, I added to your updated code `await Task.Delay(5000);` before loading the document but still didn't work. btw thank you so much for taking the time to review my code.